# Calling an ASP.NET MVC-view via ajax does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to call a view with an ajax-Call, passing an Id to the Controller-method. The Id is passed, everything is fine until I call the view in the return-Statement. Nothing happens.

```
$("#btnCreatePackage").click(function () {
    var workflowId = $("#workflowId")[0].value;
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Create", "package")',
        type: 'get',
        data: { id: workflowId },
        success: function (data) {
            return data;
        },
        timeout: 500
    });
});



public ActionResult Create(int id) {
    IList < Workflow > workflows = WorkflowService.GetWorkflowList();
    ModifyPackageViewModel vm = new ModifyPackageViewModel
    {
        Package = null,
            Workflow = workflows.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id),
            Workflows = workflows,
            Hosts = ScalingService.GetHostList(),
            SelectedHostNames = new List<string>(),
            Factor = 1
    };

    if (!vm.SelectedHostNames.Any()) {
        if (vm.Hosts.Any()) {
            vm.SelectedHostNames.Add(vm.Hosts.First().Name);
        }
    }

    return View(vm);
}
```

The curious thing is, if i#m calling the view via @Url.Action without passing the Id with the following code, it works.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Create")">
   <div class="submenu-item add">
      neues paket anlegen
   </div>
</a>

public ActionResult Create() {
    IList<Workflow> workflows = WorkflowService.GetWorkflowList();
    ModifyPackageViewModel vm = new ModifyPackageViewModel
    {
            Package = null,
            Workflow = workflows.FirstOrDefault(),
            Workflows = workflows,
            Hosts = ScalingService.GetHostList(),
            SelectedHostNames = new List<string>(),
            Factor = 1
    };

    if (!vm.SelectedHostNames.Any()) {
            if (vm.Hosts.Any())
            {
                vm.SelectedHostNames.Add(vm.Hosts.First().Name);
            }
    }

    return View(vm);
}
```

In both cases the Controller-method is called, goes through to the end without errors, in the first case nothing happens, in the second case everything is fine.

Anyone any ideas??????

Thanks, daniel

Comment: Your success handler receives a bunch of html code as `data`, but does not do anything with it. You got to display it somehow

Comment: Try adding this in the Ajax success. `$("#//ID of the div you want the view in").html(data)`

Comment: `return data;` doesn't do anything.

Comment: the return data statement is just the attempt of finalizing the ajax call, i do not need the data anywhere. The only thing i need is the id that is passed to the controller, and that is working fine. The problem is that inside the controller when the return-statement is called nothing happens, the view doesn`t render if i am passing the id. inthe other case it is working. It is a complete new view that is called, nothing within the actual view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least I fixed it, I did not need an ajax-Call, instead I just used this:

```
   $("#btnCreatePackage").click(function() {
        var workflowId = $("#workflowId")[0].value;

        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Create", "package")/' + workflowId;
    });
```

It can be that simple........

Answer (score 0):

You can't return the data from an ajax call. You can store it in a variable declared outside, or do something inside your success handler.

This works just as well with your success handler (`success: function(data) ...`). The main thing to remember is the scope of the data that is returned from your controller.

EX:

```
var outsideVariable; // You can store the data in here for later if you need to

$.ajax({
   url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Package")',
   type: 'GET',
   data: { id: workflowId }
 }).fail(function (data) {
        // Fail handler
     }).done(function (data) {
         // Success, Do Something
         YourFunctionThatProcessesData(data);
         // Or store the data into a variable that has outside scope
         outsideVariable = data;
     }).always(function () {
        //Do this no matter what
});

function YourFunctionThatProcessesData(data)
{
    // do stuff with the data
}
```